# LayoutInflater fails to inflate layout with reference to class

Tags: android

I try to inflate Layout which contain class.
I create inflater instance with:

```
 LayoutInflater inflate =(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
mRelLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
                    R.layout.app_layout, null);
```

My app_layout.xml layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.alpha"
            android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="top|right">
```

.
        .
        .

Inflation fails with exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your Panel must have a child View whose id attribute is 'R.id.panelHandle'

Thanks for help

Comment: I do not think it has the error in this line. I can not see the code about panelHandle control. could you send a logcat?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried following code, It's working perfect, Please provide full source code so I can identify the error.

Test.java

```
 LayoutInflater inflate =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
     RelativeLayout mRelLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
                         R.layout.app_layout, null);
```

app_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.alpha"
            android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="top|right" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to remove `xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.alpha"`?

Can you post the entire layout?